# Excel Formula triggering notification when not intended

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below formula that is only intended to be triggered when the proper results show in the cells outlined. When I write the formula the notification is popping up when the cells are empty. I cannot seem to detect where the error is. Advice appreciated.

```
=IF(ISNA(HLOOKUP('IPN List for CBOD'!B3,F107:K120,3)),"",IF(HLOOKUP('IPN List for CBOD'!B3,F107:K120,3)>19,"Notify Operations Foreman that effluent CBOD exceeds 19.0 mg/L, qualify sample result",""))
```

I wrote excel formula with Hlookup to indicate to lab technicians when a result is out of range. The notification is triggered when the cell is empty but should only be triggered when the result is out of range.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I linked your formulas to empty cells and the output of the formula is blank. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[The `HLOOKUP` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f) has **four** arguments.

> HLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, row_index_num, [range_lookup])
> […]
> • **Range_lookup**    Optional. A logical value that specifies whether you want HLOOKUP to find an exact match or an approximate match. If TRUE or omitted, an approximate match is returned. In other words, if an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned. If FALSE, HLOOKUP will find an exact match. If one is not found, the error value #N/A is returned.

If you exclude the argument, or explicitly set it to `TRUE`, then it will look for the previously-ordered value.  E.g. if your `table_array` contains the names "Barry" and "Paul", then a `lookup_value` of "Arthur" will return `#N/A` (because "Arthur" is alphabetically before "Barry"), a `lookup_value` of "Charles" or "Derek" will return the result for "Barry" (because they are alphabetically *after* "Barry", but *before* "Paul"), while a `lookup_value` of "Robert" or "Victor" will return the result for "Paul" (because they are alphabetically after both "Barry" and "Paul", but "Barry" is alphabetically before "Paul")

However, if you explicitly set the `range_lookup` argument to `FALSE`, then it will *only* return **exact** matches.  "Arthur", "Charles", "Derek", "Robert" and "Victor" would all give `#N/A`, and only "Barry" or "Paul" would return a non-error result.

Therefore, your code *should* work better if you change `HLOOKUP('IPN List for CBOD'!B3,F107:K120,3)` to `HLOOKUP('IPN List for CBOD'!B3,F107:K120,3,FALSE)`

Of course, you can also simplify things slightly by introducing an `IFERROR`, like so:

```
=IF(IFERROR(HLOOKUP('IPN List for CBOD'!B3, F107:K120, 3, FALSE), 0)>19, "Notify Operations Foreman that effluent CBOD exceeds 19.0 mg/L, qualify sample result", "")
```